# ODOO 10 Page wasn't loaded completely

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ping, asset-management, odoo

Since a few days I can't access my ODOO instance from the external network. The home page doesn't load completely if I use a public IP address, only the logo loads. I searched in google and I found that I have to regenerate assets ([Blank page after logging in odoo](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/blank-page-after-logging-in-odoo-112430)) but it didn't work for me.

If I ping my public address when I'am trying to load a page the ping time increases, and if I just ping my public address and I don't try to access to my odoo instance, the ping stays normal. So I don't know if it's a problem with the network, or my odoo instance, or something in the system.

I'am using odoo10 in ubuntu 16 with 5 Gb of RAM and 5 CPU core in my machine.